# i want to wrap the image as well text around the products like mug, t Shirt, crystals

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on shopping cart. pls follow the link www.photohaat.com 
In the mug section whenever the user upload the image i want to wrap the complete image onto the mug so that he/she will saw the final output immediately.

we develop this shopping cart on PHP language.

I am trying to resolve this problem but unfortunately can't get a success.

If you have any solutions regarding this than please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: If the image needs to be mapped onto the mug in "real" 3D (the mug being a cylindrical object), this is going to be very hard, if not impossible, to achieve in pure PHP. Can you install and use any server-side software? What kind of server is this running on?

Comment: Also, any kind of complex CGI will not necessarily look like the real thing. It might even be misleading. How about a fixed photograph of a sample mug?

Comment: We are using the linux server on which this is running

Comment: We are not using any server side software right now.

Comment: Have you considered doing the "proof" on the client side?  HTML5's canvas might give you the tools needed to plot an image onto a cup - if not, there's always Flash.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there is Linux 3D/Raytracing software that can do what you need, but I don't know any easy way.

*Maybe* [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) can be of help (only maybe, because IM is focused on 2D image manipulation.)

There is an [example of cylindrical mapping](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#displace_cylinder) that might serve as base for your needs. It also might not, it could well be that it is too limited (no real 3D possibilities of changing the axis, perspective, etc.)

**Update:** There's also [Cylinderize](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/index.php), a script for ImageMagick. It's not true 3D either, but looks pretty interesting:

[image]
<sub>(source: [fmwconcepts.com](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/images/img5967.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [fmwconcepts.com](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/images/img5967_cyl_vertical_full_r37p25_l112_t0_a0_black.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I am following that cylinderize script but how can i use it coz i am working in PHP and that script follows the command line.

Comment: Still i am not get any idea how to use cylinderize script on windows b'coz this scripts are written in linux. how can i use image magick script on windows??
Is GD library of php will help to me??

Comment: @Sachin ImageMagick is available for Windows. Check the downloads section.